# rospy / SMACH vs. TF

Tags: rospy, smach, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm having few SMACH states in different files and would like to use TF in some of them. There will be probably even some concurrent states so, I created helper class tf_utils (helper_methods.py) with TF listener protected by mutex. It's initialized like this:

```
_tfl = None

def get_tfl():
    
    return _tfl

def init_tfl():
    
    global _tfl
    
    if _tfl is None:
        
        _tfl = tf_utils()
```

Class tf_utils looks like this:

```
class tf_utils():
    
    def __init__(self,timeout=None):
        
        if timeout is None:
            
            timeout = rospy.Duration(5)
        
        self.timeout = timeout
        
        self.tfl = TransformListener()
        
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        
    def waitForTransform(self,f1,f2,time):
        
        ret = True
        
        self.mutex.acquire()
        
        try:
        
            self.tfl.waitForTransform(f1,f2,time,self.timeout)
            
        except tf.Exception:
            
            ret = False
        
        self.mutex.release()
        
        return ret
```

etc...

In main file, I initialize node (rospy.init_node) and tf_utils (helper_methods.init_tfl()). Then for instance frameExists method works fine while with waitForTransform I'm getting this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException'
  what():  Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.  If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call ros::Time::init()
```

Situation is same for both wall time or simulated time.

What's wrong? Or is there any other approach how to use one transform listener in more python modules / SMACH states?

UPDATE:

This is how I initialize my stuff. First I initialize rospy and then (in main) my tf listener.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('rt_decision_making')
    
    try:

        main()
        
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print "program interrupted before completion"
```

and...

```
def main():
  
  helper_methods.init_tfl()
  
  tfl = helper_methods.get_tfl()
```

UPDATE2:

I ended up with the most simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('rt_decision_making')
import rospy
import tf
from tf import TransformListener

def main():
    
  rospy.init_node('rt_decision_making')
  rospy.sleep(2)
  
  tfl =  TransformListener()
  
  rospy.sleep(2)
  
  tfl.waitForTransform("base_link", "velodyne", rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1))
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    try:

        main()
        
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print "program interrupted before completion"
```

...which works in Groovy but not in Hydro which I'm currently working with.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70174/rospy-/-smach-vs.-tf/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that rospy is initialized in before you initialize your class.  The easiest will probably be to just do that at the top of your main.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-08-05**:
Thanks for answer. Well, I'm calling "rospy.init_node" as first thing. See updated question.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-05**:
My guess is that it's happening at import time of some submodule.  You can catch the backtrace of the exception to find out where it is coming from.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-08-06**:
Thanks for hint. I tried to make the simplest possible script and it works under Groovy but not under Hydro. Looks like a bug...

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-08-06**:
Created issue for this: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/270